# Laravel 6: How to add multiple where caluses into a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, where-clause, laravel-6

I'm trying to get users of entity using the relationship

```
$users = $entity->users()->paginate(20);
```

but now I want to run multiple where conditions depending on parameters sent to the API so if I do this

```
$users = $entity->users();
//$users->where($where_array)
$users->paginate(20);
```

I get out of memory error. It's getting all users first then tries to paginate (commented out there where condition) so how can I split this query into multiple lines and run it at the end without using `DB` query

Example of what I want to do but depending on sent parameters not fixed parameters

```
$user->posts()
    ->where('active', 1)
    ->orWhere('votes', '>=', 100)
    ->get();
```

So I check

```
if(!empty($request->first_name)){
  ->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$request->first_name.'%')
}
```

And so on. I tried this

```
$where = "";

    $like_parameters = array(
        'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone'
    );

    foreach ($like_parameters as $parameter){
        if(isset($request->$parameter) &&!empty($request->$parameter)){
            $where .= "->where('$request->$parameter', 'like', '%'.$request->$parameter.'%')";
        }
    }
    
    $users = $entity->users().$where->paginate($per_page);
```

And I get `Call to a member function paginate() on string` so I want to bind `$where` to the query but not as a string but as a part of this query itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can control the query builder and add many 'where' as long as you did not fetch the result from DB using (get,find ....)

```
 $query=  $user->posts()
            ->where('active', 1)
            ->orWhere('votes', '>=', 100);

        if(!empty($request->first_name)){
            $query=$query->where('first_name', 'like', '%'.$request->first_name.'%');
            }
```

when you set all your condition and build your query as yow want, you can fetch the results:

```
        $results=$query->get();
```